# Exporting a BigQuery table with Airflow: "extract_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'; 1764166" error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm trying to use an airflow task to export a BigQuery table to a Google Cloud Storage, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
{standard_task_runner.py:93} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1819 for task export_objs_table_to_bucket (extract_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'; 1764166)
```

This is the airflow task I created:

```
task2_objs = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "export_objs_table_to_bucket",
        python_callable = callables.bq_export_to_gcs,
        op_kwargs = {
            "bucket": BUCKET,
            "blob": BLOB_OBJ,
            "project": PROJECT,
            "dataset_id": DATASET_ID,
            "table_id": TABLE_ID_OBJS
        }
    )
```

And this is the callable Python function that I use in that task, which, by the way, I took from the GCP documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-extract-table?hl=en-419

```
def bq_export_to_gcs(bucket: str, 
                     blob: str, 
                     project: str, 
                     dataset_id: str, 
                     table_id: str) -> None:

    client = bigquery.Client

    destination_uri = f"gs://{bucket}/{blob}"

    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)


    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        source = table_ref,
        destination_uris=destination_uri,
        location="europe-west1",
    )
    extract_job.result()
```

I don't really know if it has to do with Airflow or with BigQuery, but as I mentioned, I'm doing it as it is written in the BigQuery documentation so I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your use case using your provided code. The problem is that you were not able to create `client` properly because it was not instantiated correctly.

You should update the line of code `client = bigquery.Client` to `client = bigquery.Client()`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved but I wanted to show another solution anyway.

You can also use an existing operator to extract a table to `GCS`:

An example that exports a table to a CSV file with `,` as field delimiter.

```py
BigQueryToGCSOperator(
        task_id='task_id',
        source_project_dataset_table='my_project.my_dataset.my_table',
        export_format='CSV',
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=[
            'my_bucket_path'
        ],
        field_delimiter=','
    )
```